# python convert memoryview to string

Tags: python

I tried to search everywhere but could not find any relevant info.

As a result of the following code:

```
overlapped = pywintypes.OVERLAPPED()
buffer = win32file.AllocateReadBuffer(1024*4)
fullDataRead = []
hr, data = win32file.ReadFile(handle, buffer, overlapped)
n = win32file.GetOverlappedResult(handle, overlapped, 1)
read = str(data[:n])
fullDataRead.append(read)
print(fullDataRead)
```

I get

```
['<memory at 0x0000026821801348>']
```

but I need strings or bytes that are inside. Any ideas how to read a `memoryview` object? Thank you

Comment: Could you please try to update your question to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It is just a `hr, data = win32file.ReadFile()` that in ` data` returns a `memoryview` instead of `bytes` or `string`. I could not find any info how to deal with it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A `memory` object can be converted to a string using `.tobytes()` like so:

```py
a = memoryview(b'mystring')
print(a)  # <memory at 0x10cbebb98>
print(a.tobytes())  # 'mystring'
```

Comment: Note that you cannot create `memoryview` instance with `memoryview( 'mystring' )`. If you tried, you have encountered error like _**TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'**_. Rather, you may create one with `memoryview( b'mystring' )`.

Comment: Technically, you need to also add `.decode()` to convert to a `str` type.

Answer (score 6):

For Python 2.7  and 3.x you can try this:

```
a = memoryview(b'mystring')
print(a)  # <memory at 0x10cbebb98>
#for string
print(str(a,'utf8'))  # 'mystring' as UTF-8

# for bytes
print(bytes(a))  # b'mystring'
```